# How to add a custom email variable to magento 2 credit memo email?

Tags: orders, customer, magento2.4, transactional-mail, creditmemo

I need to add a custom variable based on payment method to credit memo email.

I captured the event **email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before** in my custom module, Which was dispatched on `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Sender\EmailSender.php`.

I need to add my custom variable **showrefund** to bellow set.

```
$transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'creditmemo' => $creditmemo,
            'comment' => $comment ? $comment->getComment() : '',
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
            'order_data' => [
                'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
            ]
        ];
```

I added the following code in my observer file.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $transport  = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    $order          =   $transport['order'];
    $orderId        =   $order->getEntityId();
    $orderStatus    =   $order->getState();
    $payment = $order->getPayment(); 
    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

    if($methodTitle == "Cash On Delivery"){
        $showRefundAmmount = "0";
    }else{
        $showRefundAmmount = "1";
    }
    $transport['showrefund'] = $showRefundAmmount;
    return $transport;
}
```

This way the additional attribute is not working. I tried below way in the same file

```
$transportObject = new DataObject($transport);
$this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());
```

This part also not doing the trick.

How can i add this custom variable to the email template. Can anyone help me in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed this issue. Actually the creditmemo email was sending using this file `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender.php`

not by
`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Sender\EmailSender.php`.

If i tried to set the template var using event observer, its not working fine. So i decided to override the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender.php`.

For this i use a custom module. Added the preference in di.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender" />
</config>
```

and create the **CreditmemoSender.php** file under `Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Order\Email\Sender\` path.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\CreditmemoIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo as CreditmemoResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class CreditmemoSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender{

public function send(Creditmemo $creditmemo, $forceSyncMode = false)
{
    $creditmemo->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

    if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
        $order = $creditmemo->getOrder();
        $orderId        =   $order->getEntityId();
        $orderStatus    =   $order->getState(); 

        $payment = $order->getPayment();
        if($payment->getMethod() == "cashondelivery" && !$order->hasShipments()){
            $showRefundAmmount = "";
        }elseif($payment->getMethod() != "cashondelivery"){
            $showRefundAmmount = "1";
        }elseif($payment->getMethod() == "cashondelivery" && $order->hasShipments()){
            $showRefundAmmount = "1";
        }
        
        $transport['showrefund'] = $showRefundAmmount;
        $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'order_id' => $order->getId(),
            'creditmemo' => $creditmemo,
            'creditmemo_id' => $creditmemo->getId(),
            'comment' => $creditmemo->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $creditmemo->getCustomerNote() : '',
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
            'order_data' => [
                'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
            ],
            'showrefund' => $showRefundAmmount
        ];
        $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

        /**
         * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
         */
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_creditmemo_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

        if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
            $creditmemo->setEmailSent(true);
            $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        $creditmemo->setEmailSent(null);
        $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, 'email_sent');
    }

    $this->creditmemoResource->saveAttribute($creditmemo, 'send_email');

    return false;
}
}
```